# Print value from list

Tags: python

This is the code

```
import soccer_data_api
soccer_data = soccer_data_api.SoccerDataAPI()
serie_a = soccer_data.serie_a()
print(serie_a)
```

This is the print result:

> [{'team': 'Inter', 'pos': '1', 'points': '82', 'matches_played': '33',
> 'wins': '25', 'draws': '7', 'losses': '2', 'goals_for': '74',
> 'goals_against': '29', 'goal_diff': '+45', 'top_scorer': 'Romelu
> Lukaku - 21'}, {'team': 'Milan', 'pos': '2', 'points': '69',
> 'matches_played': '34', 'wins': '21', 'draws': '6', 'losses': '7',
> 'goals_for': '62', 'goals_against': '41', 'goal_diff': '+21',
> 'top_scorer': 'Zlatan Ibrahimović - 15'}, {'team': 'Atalanta', 'pos':
> '3', 'points': '68', 'matches_played': '33', 'wins': '20', 'draws':
> '8', 'losses': '5', 'goals_for': '78', 'goals_against': '39',
> 'goal_diff': '+39', 'top_scorer': 'Luis Muriel - 19'}, {'team':
> 'Napoli', 'pos': '4', 'points': '66', 'matches_played': '33', 'wins':
> '21', 'draws': '3', 'losses': '9', 'goals_for': '73', 'goals_against':
> '37', 'goal_diff': '+36', 'top_scorer': 'Lorenzo Insigne - 17'},
> {'team': 'Juventus', 'pos': '5', 'points': '66', 'matches_played':
> '34', 'wins': '19', 'draws': '9', 'losses': '5', 'goals_for': '65',
> 'goals_against': '30', 'goal_diff': '+35', 'top_scorer': 'Cristiano
> Ronaldo - 25'}, {'team': 'Lazio', 'pos': '6', 'points': '61',
> 'matches_played': '33', 'wins': '19', 'draws': '4', 'losses': '9',
> 'goals_for': '56', 'goals_against': '46', 'goal_diff': '+10',
> 'top_scorer': 'Ciro Immobile - 18'}, {'team': 'Roma', 'pos': '7',
> 'points': '55', 'matches_played': '33', 'wins': '16', 'draws': '7',
> 'losses': '10', 'goals_for': '58', 'goals_against': '51', 'goal_diff':
> '+7', 'top_scorer': 'Jordan Veretout - 10'}, {'team': 'Sassuolo',
> 'pos': '8', 'points': '52', 'matches_played': '34', 'wins': '14',
> 'draws': '10', 'losses': '9', 'goals_for': '55', 'goals_against':
> '50', 'goal_diff': '+5', 'top_scorer': 'Domenico Berardi - 14'},
> {'team': 'Sampdoria', 'pos': '9', 'points': '42', 'matches_played':
> '34', 'wins': '12', 'draws': '6', 'losses': '15', 'goals_for': '43',
> 'goals_against': '47', 'goal_diff': '-4', 'top_scorer': 'Fabio
> Quagliarella - 11'}, {'team': 'Hellas Verona', 'pos': '10', 'points':
> '42', 'matches_played': '33', 'wins': '11', 'draws': '9', 'losses':
> '14', 'goals_for': '41', 'goals_against': '42', 'goal_diff': '-1',
> 'top_scorer': 'Antonín Barák - 7'}, {'team': 'Udinese', 'pos': '11',
> 'points': '39', 'matches_played': '32', 'wins': '10', 'draws': '9',
> 'losses': '14', 'goals_for': '38', 'goals_against': '44', 'goal_diff':
> '-6', 'top_scorer': 'Rodrigo De Paul - 8'}, {'team': 'Bologna', 'pos':
> '12', 'points': '38', 'matches_played': '34', 'wins': '10', 'draws':
> '8', 'losses': '15', 'goals_for': '44', 'goals_against': '53',
> 'goal_diff': '-9', 'top_scorer': 'Roberto Soriano - 9'}, {'team':
> 'Genoa', 'pos': '13', 'points': '36', 'matches_played': '33', 'wins':
> '8', 'draws': '12', 'losses': '13', 'goals_for': '37',
> 'goals_against': '48', 'goal_diff': '-11', 'top_scorer': 'Mattia
> Destro - 11'}, {'team': 'Fiorentina', 'pos': '14', 'points': '34',
> 'matches_played': '33', 'wins': '8', 'draws': '10', 'losses': '15',
> 'goals_for': '42', 'goals_against': '54', 'goal_diff': '-12',
> 'top_scorer': 'Dušan Vlahović - 17'}, {'team': 'Spezia', 'pos': '15',
> 'points': '34', 'matches_played': '33', 'wins': '8', 'draws': '10',
> 'losses': '16', 'goals_for': '43', 'goals_against': '63', 'goal_diff':
> '-20', 'top_scorer': "M'Bala Nzola - 9"}, {'team': 'Benevento', 'pos':
> '16', 'points': '31', 'matches_played': '33', 'wins': '7', 'draws':
> '10', 'losses': '17', 'goals_for': '37', 'goals_against': '68',
> 'goal_diff': '-31', 'top_scorer': 'Gianluca Lapadula - 6'}, {'team':
> 'Torino', 'pos': '17', 'points': '31', 'matches_played': '33', 'wins':
> '6', 'draws': '13', 'losses': '13', 'goals_for': '46',
> 'goals_against': '56', 'goal_diff': '-10', 'top_scorer': 'Andrea
> Belotti - 12'}, {'team': 'Cagliari', 'pos': '18', 'points': '31',
> 'matches_played': '34', 'wins': '8', 'draws': '7', 'losses': '18',
> 'goals_for': '39', 'goals_against': '56', 'goal_diff': '-17',
> 'top_scorer': 'João Pedro - 15'}, {'team': 'Parma', 'pos': '19',
> 'points': '20', 'matches_played': '32', 'wins': '3', 'draws': '11',
> 'losses': '19', 'goals_for': '36', 'goals_against': '70', 'goal_diff':
> '-34', 'top_scorer': 'Juraj Kucka, Hernani - 7'}, {'team': 'Crotone',
> 'pos': '20', 'points': '18', 'matches_played': '33', 'wins': '5',
> 'draws': '3', 'losses': '26', 'goals_for': '42', 'goals_against':
> '85', 'goal_diff': '-43', 'top_scorer': 'Simeon Nwankwo - 19'}]

I want to print like this:
Inter 1 82 so without key (team for example)

Comment: You have a list of dicts. You need to iterate the list to get every dict and then print the keys you want. With what part of that are you having troubles exactly? Stack Overflow is not for asking for code. Is for asking for help with your code...

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Answer (score 4):

`serie_a` is a list of dicts, so change `print(serie_a)` to:

```
for x in serie_a: 
    print(f"{x['team']} {x['pos']} {x['points']}")
```

Output:

```
Inter 1 82
Milan 2 69
Atalanta 3 68
Napoli 4 66
Juventus 5 66
...
```

Comment: The right way to do it with a loop. Maybe remove the commas since the desired output is "Iter 1 82"

Comment: Since this was the fastest complete answer, I would select this as the acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would try it like this:

```
print(serie_a[0]["team"], serie_a[0]["pos"], serie_a[0]["points"])
```

The result should be like what you wrote:
`Inter 1 82`

Of course, if you want all teams printed, you can put it in a loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
print(serie_a[0]['team'], serie_a[0]['pos'], serie_a[0]['points'])
```

Use `[0]` for the first entry in the list, to print the whole list you can use:

```
for i in serie_a:
    print(i['team'], i['pos'], i['points'])
```

Comment: Is better to use `for x in serie_a` instead of  `for i in range(len(serie_a))`. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32930246/python-for-loops-for-i-in-range0-lenlist-vs-for-i-in-list

Comment: I agree with you, this is better practice.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
for i in serie_a:
    print(f"{i['team']} {i['pos']} {i['points']}")
```

Comment: this show the string without formatting, you miss the `f` in the `print`

Comment: Please explain how your code works and why it produces the correct result